# Adding an .exe to default path without adding the directory

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

For example, I want to add notepad++ to my PATH, however the directory also contains `uninstall.exe` and several other files/executables and I don't want them to "pollute" my path. Can I just add the one `notepad++.exe`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add a batch script to a directory that is in your path, that looks something like this:

```
@echo off

:: Notepad++ execution

if [%1]==[-h] goto :HELP
if [%1]==[--help] goto :HELP
if [%1]==[/?] goto :HELP
goto :START

:START
start "" /i "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\notepad++\notepad++.exe" %*
goto :EOF

:HELP
echo -------------------------------
echo Notepad++ Command Argument Help
echo -------------------------------
echo Usage :
echo.
echo notepad++ [--help] [-multiInst] [-noPlugins] [-lLanguage] [-nLineNumber] [-cColumnNumber] [-xPos] [-yPos] [-nosession] [-notabbar] [-ro] [-systemtray] [-loadingTime] [fullFilePathName]
echo.
echo     --help : This help message
echo     -multiInst : Launch another Notepad++ instance
echo     -noPlugins : Launch Notepad++ without loading any plugin
echo     -l : Launch Notepad++ by applying indicated language to the file to open
echo     -n : Launch Notepad++ by scrolling indicated line on the file to open
echo     -c : Launch Notepad++ on scrolling indicated column on the file to open
echo     -x : Launch Notepad++ by indicating its left side position on the screen
echo     -y : Launch Notepad++ by indicating its top position on the screen
echo     -nosession : Launch Notepad++ without any session
echo     -notabbar : Launch Notepad++ without tabbar
echo     -ro : Launch Notepad++ and make the file to open read only
echo     -systemtray : Launch Notepad++ directly in system tray
echo     -loadingTime : Display Notepad++ loading time
echo     -alwaysOnTop : Make Notepad++ always on top
echo     fullFilePathName : file name to open (absolute or relative path name)
echo.
goto :EOF

:EOF
```

You can name it `notepad++.cmd`.  The help section allows you to easily get information on the switches.

I put all such scripts and command line programs in a directory which is added to `%PATH%`:
`C:\Users\Public\Command\`
...and that directory is synced to all computers and virtual machines.

Answer (score 13):

Create a batch file with contents like the following:

```
@"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" %*
```

This should be saved as a `.bat` file, such as `git.bat` in a directory that's in your `PATH`.

`@` suppresses echoing the command to the invoking shell. The quotations `""` prevent white space being interpreted as argument delimiters. `%*` pastes any arguments to the batch file, to the quoted executable instead.

You can now invoke the executable using the part of the batch file name before `.bat`. In my case, `git`.

References:

- [Adding Python to Windows path using a small batch file](http://code.google.com/p/tryton/wiki/AddingPythonToWindowsPath)
- [Adding Python to Windows path using a small batch file - forum thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/comp.lang.python/QhdWzHh1yLA/sMwR6Pa6VlYJ)

Comment: For many programs that will hang up CMD until you close it.  You need to use `start` to avoid that, as shown in my answer.

Comment: @paradroid: Thanks, but it's standard terminal behaviour to remain attached to the parent unless asked. The user should do `start git` rather than have it done for them. The batch script would act better if it `exec`d into the requested process but this isn't possible on Windows: http://serverfault.com/questions/315077/is-there-a-windows-cmd-equivalent-of-unix-shells-exec. I could prepend `call` but it would be pedantic and mostly pointless.

Answer (score 3):

Drag a shortcut to `notepad++.exe` to `C:\Windows\System32`.

---

Alternatively, as suggested by @Synetech inc., you could place your shortcuts in a separate directory (e.g. `C:\Shortcuts`), and then add that directory to `%PATH%`:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Shortcuts"
```

---

As some of the comments indicate, this only works from the Run dialog. In order to get the shortcuts to launch from a command prompt, you need to add the shortcut extension (.LNK) to your PATHEXT environment variable.

```
setx PATHEXT %pathext%;.LNK
```

> **References:**
>
> [How can I start applications easily with the Run dialog box?](http://www.overclock.net/faqs/15588-how-can-i-start-applications-easily.html)

Comment: This is the preferred solution (as opposed to a batch file); create a shortcut to it in a (different) directory in the path—don’t pollute Windows’ directories! I have a folder specifically for this purpose called `Shortcuts`.

Comment: That's the wrong syntax for `setx`.  You do not use an equals sign, and IIRC, you need to enclose the whole path in quotes, if the current `%PATH%` has spaces in it (which it will).

Comment: And doesn’t `SETX` use tildes for variables instead of percents to avoid expanding them? I know that some env-var setting tool does…

Comment: @Synetech: No, it doesn't. You could use bangs when using `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` when you do not want percents expanded in a batch file though.

Comment: Well something does, maybe `setenv` or something (though I’m pretty sure it was a version of `setx`); I’ll check my drive. Ah, I thought so; it was indeed an [older version of SETX](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/1808287/Adding-Environment-Variables-to-Variables.aspx).

Comment: @Synetech: `setx /?` says that you can still use tildes (they do get expanded), but I never noticed that before, and I'm sure that the syntax has not changed since the version in the `Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit` (which is probably the same version now included as standard).

Comment: Well there you go; multiple ways to suit the situation. (Though frankly, I find that using the command-line always results in a *potential* for problems due to escaping no matter what escape character you choose (eg you can’t have strings that contain ‘%’ and/or ‘!’ and/or ‘~’, etc.) It just can’t be like say, C++ strings where you can create *any* string, including ones that contain the escape character.)

Comment: This doesn't work. By default (I'm dragging git.exe), "git - Shortcut", renaming this to combinations of "git.exe", "git", "git.cmd" etc. has no effect. It won't acknowledge the shortcut.

Comment: This only works when invoking from the `Run As` dialog, it didn't work from the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a **symbolic link** using `mklink` in a folder in the Path.

e.g. (in Administrator command prompt)

```
mklink "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Paths\np.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

The App Paths registry key does exactly this: set the path to notepad++.exe to "\program files\..." and you'll be able to launch it from Start-Run, cmd, ... just like any executable from a directory in %PATH%.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822400/register-an-exe-so-you-can-run-it-from-any-command-line-in-windows

Comment: This will not make it executable from cmd - only from start-run, or in cmd you have to prefix it with "start" as in "start myapp.exe"

Comment: The Command Prompt this, agreed, lacks the ability to recognize this variable. PowerShell does recognize it. This solution, more importantly, only applies to the directory, and hence, off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like any of the solutions presented here, so I tried something else.

1. Install [link shell extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html#download) (more info [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/))
2. Create a folder somewhere to store all your shortcuts like [Marteen suggests](https://superuser.com/a/288197/5106) and add it to your `%PATH%`. I created `C:\Shortcuts` and used [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/download) to add it to my PATH.
3. Right-click the file you want to add to your path (in Explorer) and click "Pick Link Source"
4. Right-click in folder you just created and click `Drop As > Symbolink Link`.
5. Rename the symbolink link if you want.

That's it. You should be able to access your program via the command-line now. If you just added the new folder to your PATH, you will have to restart cmd.exe or Cmder or ConEmu or whatever it is you use. After that, you can add new programs without restarting.