# How use windows command-line to run tools like SVN and MYSQL without going to theirs respective path

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, command-line, mysql, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding an .exe to default path without adding the directory](https://superuser.com/questions/228592/adding-an-exe-to-default-path-without-adding-the-directory)
>   [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Hi I would like to use windows command-line to run tools like SVN and MYSQL without going to theirs respective path.

How can I just type "mysql -u root" or "svn up" straigthway in the command prompt?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the global variable PATH, you will need to add new directory entries for each folder which contains items (such as mysql and svn) you want to have available globally. Make sure you separate each folder (absolute path to the FOLDER not the FILE) with semicolons ";". Once you do this is may be reflected immediately, but it also may require a reboot.

Comment: it would need you to log off and on, as opposed to reboot